# Why including a fork() call creates more loops

Tags: perl, loops, fork

When I include `fork()` function call in the loop, the loop executes more than the expected times. For the sake of simplicity, I have chosen only two iterations; you can test with more than that.

I have tried setting the `autoflush on` but that doesn't seem to work.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Handle;

$|++; #autoflush on
STDOUT->flush();

for my $i (1 .. 2) {
    print "Normal => $i\n";
}
print "\n";

for my $i (1 .. 2) {
    my $pid = fork();
    if(not defined($pid)) {
       die "cannot fork\n";
    } elsif (not $pid) {
       print "Child  => $i\n";
    } else {
       print "Parent => $i\n";
       wait();
    }
}
```

Actual Output

```
Normal => 1
Normal => 2

Parent => 1
Child  => 1
Parent => 2
Child  => 2
Parent => 2
Child  => 2
```

Expected Output

```
Normal => 1
Normal => 2

Parent => 1
Child  => 1
Parent => 2
Child  => 2
```

Please help me understanding what is wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar question and answer can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/8318556/542995

Because your code will have the first child to start iterating exactly the same as the parent does.

So, just to simply, in order to prevent extra loop. You may have to `exit` the child job and put `wait();` for parent in response to finished job in a separate loop. And, that will lead to what you expected.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $n = 2;

for my $i (1 .. $n) {
  my $pid = fork;
  if (not $pid) {
    print "Child: $i\n";
    exit;
  } else {
    print "Parent $i\n";
  }
}

for (1 .. $n) {
   wait();
   print "Job finished\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Parent 1
Parent 2
Child: 1
Child: 2
Job finished
Job finished
```

Answer (score 3):

You end up calling `fork()` ***three times***, for a total of *four* processes.

Here's one possible execution sequence that would produce the output you see:

```
Process 1       Process 2       Process 3       Process 4
$i == 1
fork----------->$i == 1
"Parent 1"
                "Child 1"
$i == 2
fork--------------------------->$i == 2
"Parent 2"
                                "Child 2"
                $i == 2
                fork--------------------------->$i == 2
                "Parent 2"
                                                "Child 2"
 wait
                reaped          
                                zombie          zombie
```

Comment: Sorry! couldn't understand it. Please elaborate. What should I do to prevent the extra loop?

Comment: After further analysis I found that it's even more complex than I initially thought. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

As mentionned in [Jim Garisson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55488644/4990392), you end up calling `fork` three times, thus creating 3 additional processes.

Here is a simpler example, which might help you understand what's happening:

```
say "Start";
fork();
say "Middle";
fork();
say "End";
```

One of the possible outputs is:

```
Start
Middle
Middle
End
End
End
End
```

The initial process says "Start", then forks, so you end up with two processes, each of which says "Middle" and then forks, each creating one additional process, and thus you end up with 4 processes saying "End".

A graphical representation might be useful:

```
 "Start"
    |
  fork()
    |
    ------------------------------
    |                            |
 "Middle"                     "Middle"
    |                            |
  fork()                       fork()
    |                            |
    ---------------              ---------------
    |             |              |             |
  "End"         "End"          "End"         "End"
```